# Why azure takes so long to create an windows core server container instance?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances

Recently started to look into azure container instance for windows preview.
When creating a container from images ( "microsoft/iis" or "microsoft/windowsservercore" ) azure taking 10-12 minutes to make its ProvisioningState to Succeeded.

Just wanted to confirm will this remain same in future or it will improve as we are betting high on ACI for processing small duration workloads.

I have created container instance with PowerShell as well as from Azure portal itself.

Answer (score 3):

The startup time for a container in Azure Container Instances is mostly a function of the size of the container image that you're deploying, since we need to pull and extract the image in order to start it. The Windows Server Core image is currently 5GB, so it will take some time to pull and extract it in ACI. Smaller images, such as those based on Nanoserver will start much faster.

Comment: Is there any plan to improve it, may by keeping window server core image locally available so don't need to always fetch it.
Our all execution requests are the .NET full framework and PowerShell dependent, so we can not use Nano server.
Can you suggest other approaches as our application get request from users to execute smaller workloads ( 1 min to 30 min or more ), So we thought to move executions request to ACI by creating container at runtime (dedicated VM is costly and does not scale very well) but this is a big bottleneck if ACI takes 10-12 minutes to just create a container.